Garmin Watch(Instinct 2) and FIeld Maps Integrations
I recently purchased a Garmin Instinct 2.  I wanted to see if I could use the GPS in the watch to collect data. I can add it as a location provider on Field Maps.  When I choose it as a provider, it says not connected.  However, I check the status on the watch and it says it is connected to my phone.  Can I not use this watch as a GPS with Field Maps?

are you using the Garmin Connect™ App? https://www.garmin.com/en-US/p/125677/

Yes,  I use the Garmin COnnect app
